# Query an API which blocks CORS

Tags: java, rest, api, cors

I have an app which needs to query an API which blocks cross-origin requests. Right now, my approach is to query my *own* API, which then queries the 3rd party API, and then relay the results to frontend. So basically I have set-up proxy endpoints.

This results in extra load on my server which I want to avoid. Is there a way I could do this directly from my frontend code and not have proxy endpoints in backend?

For example, say the following endpoint:
https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-dynamic
If you go directly hit the browser with it, it runs fine. But when I use say Angular 2 http to fetch response from it, it is blocked.

Comment: I think you should allow CORS on the server where that APIs is hosted.

Comment: I don't have control over that API.

Comment: Having a proxy is not a bad thing at all. Check Netflix Zuul resources and stories references on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul) page to see why is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way I could do this directly from my frontend code and not have proxy endpoints in backend?

No. That is the point of CORS being disabled. If you cannot control the server to either disable CORS or allow it for the origin server where your app is running, then you must use a proxy, either by setting up a proxy when serving vi node or by configuring apache/nginx accordingly.